# My Reporting Services 2008 web service URL only shows a directory listing

Tags: web-services, ssrs-2008

I have reporting services setup on my machine.  I can access http://localhost:8080/Reports_SQL2008 and the reports manager works fine.

When I try accessing the web service URL (http://localhost:8080/ReportServer_SQL2008) all I get is a directory listing that looks something like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

              February 4, 2010 9:08 AM         Data Sources
              February 4, 2010 9:08 AM         ReportProject1


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.0.1600.22
```

I would like to use the web service inside of VS2008, I expected to be able to add a Service Reference to the Reporting Services Web Service URL, but of course it fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the web service url is actually:

http://localhost:8080/ReportServer_SQL2008/ReportService2005.asmx

Comment: As a general rule, this is `<Web Service URL>/ReportService2005.asmx`